# JavaScript linking arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to connect two different arrays into one. For example  we have two arrays

```
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
y = [5,4,8,5,5,5,5,5,5];
```

I'm interested into get array

```
var xyAr = [[1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 8]...];
```

Comment: `xy = x.map(function(item, i) { return [item, y[i]]; });`

Comment: `x.map(function(el,i){ return [el,y[i]];})` but seriously you learn nothing by not doing this yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is called `zip` in other languages and can be done in js like this:

```
function zip(a, b) {
    return a.map(function(x, i) {
        return [x, b[i]];
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kQuuz/

Here's a version that accepts a variable number of parameters:

```
function zip() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return args[0].map(function(_, i) {
        return args.map(function(a) { return a[i] })
    });
}
```

Use it like this:

```
zip(array1, array2, array3)
```

Comment: Doesn't `zip` generally accept a variable number of arguments?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: thanks for the suggestion, I added a vararg version.

Comment: You don't need varargs for this. OP said: "I want to connect 2 different arrays into one.". If you were writing a library I'd agree with you, but in this case you're just adding a pointless complication.